# Why was specifically formed question closed as offtopic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66903446/4928642) and now it is closed with this reason:

> Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can [edit the question](/posts/66903446/edit) or [post a new one](/help/how-to-ask).

Let's stick to the rules:

- Does it contain the code that works not as expected?
- Yes.

- Does it contain actual result and expected result?
- Yes.

- Is the code in form of [mcve](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?
- Seems short enough.
- But is it complete and verifiable?
- Yes, the question contains full code in the snippet. Moreover you can click <kbd>run</kbd> button there and see exactly the result that is mentioned in the question.

So what's wrong with it and why it should be closed?

Comment: "Seems short enough", but it's complete and verifiable?

Comment: @Braiam you can click "Run" on the snippet. It reproduces the behaviour reported in the question.

Comment: @Braiam, yes it is. If you run the snippet you'll see exatly the output mentiond in the question.

Comment: @VLAZ It was more a tongue not in check arguing that not only walls of code can run afoul of the MCVE. I can have a wall of code that is minimal,  complete and verifiable.

Comment: It wasn't closed as off-topic, it was closed as unclear. Off-topic has a specific meaning which does not include unclear. Personally I would've gone with no-repro, as it's not going to be of any use to anyone in future (*"this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."*). You knew it was tongue in cheek, you knew it wouldn't be received well and.... it wasn't, I see no problem here.

Comment: It was probably closed as unclear because the real question you have (why does it stop after four iterations) is not obvious unless you read the full comment chain. The question you state in the question "Why does the loop go in the wrong direction": because you increment in each iteration. I can see why people are confused that you expect the loop to go downwards when you call ++.

Comment: Since today is a sensitive day, just want to put it here: [Why can't my program compile under Windows 7 in French?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22780466/2821954)

Comment: Closing such april fools day question is correct, as it is not asking for problem solving. The massive downvotes hopefully helps to clean the site again

Comment: Arguably, it is a duplicate of the question about HTML comments, but "unclear"? Doesn't look like it. Even if this April Fool's questions are not welcome, we shouldn't misuse close votes, should we?

Comment: I don't thing the issue is April Fool. Just the way the code is formated and explain look like a catch101. It feels like the  "zero-width space" question, where a user use `"var a"` and "`var a+[\u200b]`". And I find those unpleasant.

Comment: @DragandDrop, formating is essential - see comments on the question. And without comments such formatting will be stuped. And it's my own code and question, it's not copied from anywhere.

Comment: @DragandDrop, but there is no any special chars. All the code is fully readable without any confusing chars.

Comment: If the site weren't already inundated with stupid questions, this would be funnier. As it is, not so much.

Comment: There isn't really any particular written rule against this question, but if I had to try to articulate it, I'd say it "wasn't asked in good faith." It's a bit of an I'll-know-it's-pornography-when-I-see-it kind of reasoning, but this question was clearly artificially constructed with the intent to confuse and waste people's time. (And entertain as a side effect…)

Comment: Adding a spam answer just to reserve the creation date is the cherry on top of this question.

Comment: @deceze, show an interesting feature is a good faith as I think.

Comment: @Tom, there will be good anser a bit later, I have to post a placeholder to have ability to write the answer after the question gets closed again. And I don't usderstand what do you mean by "reserve the creation date".

Comment: Again, if we want to argue on technicalities, there's no particular reason against this question. But: Nobody. Writes. Code. Like. This. If they do, they deserve what's coming to them.  So the first step would have been to format this question in a sane manner, and that would have solved the issue. If it was a different, more realistic code sample, this might have all been different.

Comment: @deceze, why don't you write an aswer here?

Comment: I'm in the process of organising my thoughts enough to do so…

Comment: @Tom, now the answer is really an answer.

Answer (score 10):

You've found a funky implementation detail of the Javascript engine (that any line starting with `-->` must be treated as a single-line comment) and have constructed an artificial problem around this. If you want to be charitable you might say that you wanted to educate and entertain (in which case you could have self-answered this), the less charitable interpretation would be *"look at me and this tidbit I found"*. But this Javascript quirk was designed precisely in a manner that it's virtually impossible to ever cause an issue in practice, because **nobody writes code like this.** You're bound to run into a ton of issues like ASI if you actually do, so this would be the least of your worries.

The first thing that should have been done is to format the question in a sane, readable, *minimal* manner, which would have solved the problem. So this is basically a [golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) or [puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) question, which we don't do here.

If this code sample would have been more realistic and didn't depend on this particular nonsense formatting and might actually be encountered by someone in the wild, this would have been a perfectly fine question to answer.

Happy April 1st though, and thanks for the edutainment.

Comment: I reserved an answer and going to write explanation a few hours later. There is a notice in the question, so that reader can spend no time on the quesion if he doesn't want to research it. So the only point left is that it's an artificial problem. I've never seen the rule that artificial problems are offtopic - does it exist?

Comment: As discussed in the comments under the question: no. You have found a loophole in the written rules. Doesn't mean we can't enforce the *spirit* of the rules. If you made up a problem to illustrate something, then answer it immediately with a self-answered question. Why wait a few hours?  To confuse people and make them waste their time. Arguably with the noble goal of edutaining them, but it's needless confusion nonetheless.

Comment: You could've talk about wasting of time if there was no notice in the begining if the post. But wheen it is - why do you think so? Waiting initially was because it's very strange to post some kind of puzzle togeter with solution and now because currently I'm busy vith another activities and can't post a full answer right now.

Comment: A disclaimer that your post doesn't adhere to the rules doesn't absolve it of the rules.

Comment: Actually the disclimer is that it _does adhere,_ but actully posted for fun, not because of real problem.

Comment: I mean, are you *really* arguing that you would have posted this as a serious question any other day if it wasn't April 1st, and that this kind of post should be generally accepted here?

Comment: I wouldn't post it in another day, but I think it is ontopic and allowed according to the rules.

Comment: Again: would you want to argue that this kind of post is *generally* acceptable on SO? Not only you and not only today, but that we could expect a few dozen of these every day? I hope not. That's specifically what http://puzzling.stackexchange.com is for. Go there and have fun. — Postulating this as a given, why should we make an exception for *you, today*?

Comment: There is dozen of worth questions every day and nobody cares. Puzzling is not about programming. Maybe code golf, but I think it is offtopic there too as dosn't ask to write code.

Comment: Puzzling is also [*somewhat* about programming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle). I've said all I have to say, going on I'd just be repeating myself.

Comment: The answer is ready.